# .Net 4.0 WCF Service failing when passing parameters

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I am trying to test a WCF service using the basichttpbinding endpoint from the WCF test client. I can test methods that I don't pass parameters to with no issue, but when I need to pass a parameter I get the following error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible
>   causes: The service is offline or
>   inaccessible; the client-side
>   configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid.
>   Refer to the stack trace for more
>   detail. You can try to recover by
>   starting a new proxy, restoring to
>   default configuration, or refreshing
>   the service.
>
> An error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String
>   action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   IErouter.GetClientSearch(String
>   surname, String forename, String
>   street, String postcode)    at
>   ErouterClient.GetClientSearch(String
>   surname, String forename, String
>   street, String postcode)

Due to the fact I can make calls to parameterless methods this error makes no sense to me.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IErouter
{
    #region Client Search

    [OperationContract]
    SelectClientSearch_Result[] GetClientSearch(
        string surname, string forename, string street, string postcode);

    #endregion

    #region Changes

    [OperationContract]
    ChangeForBlackBerry[] GetClientChanges(string blackberryPin);

    [OperationContract]
    bool AcceptChange(int changeId, string blackberryPin);

    [OperationContract]
    bool AcknowledgeChange(int changeId, string blackberryPin);

    [OperationContract]
    ChangeForBlackBerry[] GetManagerChangesForShiftType(string blackberryPin, 
        string date, int shiftTypeId);

    [OperationContract]
    ClientDetailChangeViewModel GetClientDetailChange(int changeId);

    #endregion

    #region Client Details

    [OperationContract]
    ClientDetailViewModel GetClientDetails(int clientId);

    [OperationContract]
    SelectUserLevel_Result GetUserLevel(string blackberryPin);

    #endregion

    #region Useful Contacts

    [OperationContract]
    SelectAdminCentreTelNo_Result[] GetAdminCentreTelNos();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetDutyEmail();

    [OperationContract]
    SelectDutyManager_Result[] GetDutyManagerTelNos();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetGhaHandyTelNo();

    [OperationContract]
    SelectHospitalNos_Result[] GetHospitalTelNos();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetICTTelNo();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetMAHMobileTelNo();

    [OperationContract]
    SelectMyManagerNo_Result[] GetMyManagerTelNo(string blackberryPin);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetNHSDirectTelNo();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetOOHEmail();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetOOHTelNo();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetOperationsEmail();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetOperationsTelNo();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetOtherHandyPersonTelNo();

    [OperationContract]
    SelectSWTelNos_Result[] GetSWTelNo();

    #endregion

    #region Gaurdian 24 Visit Monitoring

    [OperationContract]
    string StartVisitMonitoring(int clientId, int activityDuration, 
        string activityText, string blackberryPin);

    [OperationContract]
    string StopVisitMonitoring(int clientId, string activityId, 
        string blackberryPin);

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you post your service & data contracts?

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch this before, but I see "An error occurred while executing the command definition", do you happen to be using the entity framework?

Comment: And what is the inner exception? did you set [DataContract] attribute on your data classes (ClientDetailViewModel and other)

Comment: Did you tried calling GetHospitalTelNos() or GetOperationsTelNo()?

Comment: @The_smallest - yes I have tried those methods and they work fine. Unfortunately I've had to leave as its been closed due to the bad weather! I will check your other points tomorrow

Comment: @scmccart - yes we are using the entity framework.

Comment: @littlechris is there an inner exception? That message about the command definition means a query is going wrong, and the placement of the exception make it seem like the query is executing during serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was coming from elsewhere in the application... WCF errors are not the greatest! :)

Comment: I know this is a pretty old comment, but can you describe the source of your errors?

Answer (score 1):

It could be serialization error - check if you have [DataContract] or [Serializable] at your return class SelectClientSearch_Result.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth trying to add the following to the web.config:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://host:port"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

If that doesn't work, you could try adding the above and removing the  elements: `<host></host>` (idea from the last link I've linked)

Just adding the following to the web.config may help.

```
<system.serviceModel>        
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    
</system.serviceModel>
```

The sites I've read are:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731336.aspx
http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=7719
```

One mentioned the WCF service behaving exactly like an ASMX service which is why I thought it may be relevant.

EDIT:

May be worth a quick read? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958478

Comment: Cheers james -but no joy with this. Need to get to the inner exception to get more info